# SWIG disabled cursor print on MacOS terminal console and need to type "reset" to restore

Tags: python, linux, macos, terminal, swig

After a large C-to-Python SWIG target is built, typing from keyboard will not show anything on the console. The cursor just stays at the same place. But when clicking "return", the command can be executed (eg. typing "ls", can't see ls but pressing "return" it can list the directories). Typing "reset" on console will solve problem. Does anyone know which part of the swig disables the print and how to avoid that?

I don't have screenshot since this is observed on a proprietary build system. If needed I can try to record with some redaction.

Environment:

- MacOS (Ventura 13.2.1) terminal
- cmake 3.25.2
- swig 4.1.1
- Python 3.8.8
- Xcode 14.2

What have I tried:

- Always typing "reset" to bring back the console print
- Searched online and didn't see any discussion related to this issue
- have not read swig documentation on how the SWIG compilation interferes with console output

Expectation:

- console behaves normally after swig is built (type "123", shows "123")

Update 3/1/2023:

default stty -a:

```
speed 9600 baud; 44 rows; 152 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

stty -a after swig run:

```
speed 9600 baud; 45 rows; 152 columns;
lflags: -icanon isig iexten -echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

stty -a after running reset again:

```
speed 9600 baud; 45 rows; 152 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff -ixany imaxbel iutf8
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: Instead of `reset` can you try `stty echo` and see if that restores it? One typical way that shell user-input echo gets turned off is `stty -echo`, so maybe it's that.

Comment: actually, while we're at it, potentially a useful debugging thing would be `stty -a` before and after running the build. Shoul get all terminal settings, you can diff them and see if anything is getting messed up.  (I don't think anything should be especially sensitive. eg it won't show any environment variables)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, let me try on my build and update

Comment: Added stty prints in the post

Comment: Looks like I can add a custom cmake target to run "stty echo" at the end of build to overcome this issue. I would like to see if there's better solution to avoid this from swig target itself

Comment: I don't know much about swig, but I'd do a quick search in the project directory/build scripts for `-echo` and see if one of the targets is 'helpfully' turning it off and then forgot to turn it back on. If it's not that, I'm sure other folks might know more than I do. glad you have a workaround though!

Comment: I tried the workaround but it doesn't help. 
add_custom_target(echo_restore ALL COMMAND bash -c "stty echo" COMMENT "Restoring terminal echo...")
add_dependencies(echo_restore my_last_target)
Can you please point to me which file you see -echo is used? I am also searching locally (my workspace is several GB and has dozens of swigs)

Comment: In case you know how to control terminal setting via cmake target please also let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, no official solution so far, but a quick workaround to fix this issue is to add "stty echo" in shell prompt so echo will always be restored

```
vim ~/.bash_profile.sh
restore_echo() {
  stty echo
}

PS1="$(restore_echo)\u\$ "
```